# Tour of Go exercise #10: Crawler

Tags: go

I'm going through the Go Tour and I feel like I have a pretty good understanding of the language except for concurrency.

[slide 10](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10) is an exercise that asks the reader to parallelize a web crawler (and to make it not cover repeats but I haven't gotten there yet.)

Here is what I have so far:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, ch chan string) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintln(err)
        return
    }

    ch <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, ch)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string, 100)
    go Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, ch)

    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

My question is, where do I put the `close(ch)` call.

If I put a `defer close(ch)` somewhere in the `Crawl` method, then the program ends up writing to a closed channel from one of the spawned goroutines, because the call to `Crawl` will return before the spawned goroutines do.

If I omit the call to `close(ch)`, as I demonstrate it, the program deadlocks in the main function ranging the channel because the channel is never closed when all goroutines has returned.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A look at the Parallelization section of [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#parallel) leads to ideas for the solution. Essentually you have to close the channel on each return route of the function. Actually this is a nice use case of the defer statement:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, ret chan string) {
    defer close(ret)
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        ret <- err.Error()
        return
    }

    ret <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q", url, body)

    result := make([]chan string, len(urls))
    for i, u := range urls {
        result[i] = make(chan string)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, result[i])
    }

    for i := range result {
        for s := range result[i] {
            ret <- s
        }
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    result := make(chan string)
    go Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, result)

    for s := range result {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

The essential difference to your code is that every instance of Crawl gets its own return channel and the caller function collects the results in its return channel.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to account for one of the requirements of that exercise, which is "Don't fetch the same URL twice". I've posted an answer that I believe is similarly idiomatic but also has the deduplication functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63611170/1190975

Answer (score 22):

I went with a completely different direction with this one. I might have been mislead by the tip about using a map.

```
// SafeUrlMap is safe to use concurrently.
type SafeUrlMap struct {
    v   map[string]string
    mux sync.Mutex
}

func (c *SafeUrlMap) Set(key string, body string) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    // Lock so only one goroutine at a time can access the map c.v.
    c.v[key] = body
    c.mux.Unlock()
}

// Value returns mapped value for the given key.
func (c *SafeUrlMap) Value(key string) (string, bool) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    // Lock so only one goroutine at a time can access the map c.v.
    defer c.mux.Unlock()
    val, ok := c.v[key]
    return val, ok
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, urlMap SafeUrlMap) {
    defer wg.Done()
    urlMap.Set(url, body)

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for _, u := range urls {
        if _, ok := urlMap.Value(u); !ok {
            wg.Add(1)
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, urlMap)
        }
    }

    return
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    urlMap := SafeUrlMap{v: make(map[string]string)}

    wg.Add(1)
    go Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, urlMap)
    wg.Wait()

    for url := range urlMap.v {
        body, _ := urlMap.Value(url)
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  The only thing I would add to make it a bit cleaner is put `defer wg.Done()` at the top of `Crawl` so that you don't need to call it before every return.

Comment: yeh, that's much nicer than what I've done. I actually had a bit of trouble with that bit, using defer would have made things much easier.

Comment: I had went with almost similar approach. In the official solution though, they're also handling the case of avoiding parallel fetch of the same url. That is, they add the url to the map right before fetching so that no 2 goroutines will fetch the same url simultaneously

Comment: I seem to remember not being able to find the official solution, maybe that's the real issue?

Comment: The first "body" in Crawl is undefined :/ otherwise I think this is the solution intended in the exercise :)

Comment: You can save a few lines by using `sync.Map` instead.

Comment: to me this solution is completely wrong, no matter when or how you "lock" the resource, you still have race conditions while you try to set the resource, you should lock and return error if it was previously set
i.e.
`if _, ok := urlMap.Value(u); !ok {
    wg.Add(1)`

who said that between the Value call and the wg.Add, the !ok has not changed? no one
i.e.

`for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
   go Crawl(same_url, ...) // this case is exactly the one of the crawler (backlinks)
}

func Crawl(url, ...) {
    urlMap.Set(url, body)
}`

this is a race condition by definition

Comment: @ROLO I came across this question today and my code is also like this answer.  Do you mean between the time when `!ok` is evaluated and `wg.Add(1)`, another goroutine may set that url as visited so we may visit this url one more time? Could you share your answer?

Comment: Yeah @ROLO is right, there is a race condition on that check, you need to return to not visit the same url more than once and to correctly unlock the map you need to first lock then see if the value is set then unlock and if it is not set then set the value and unlock it.

Answer (score 11):

O(1) time lookup of url on map instead of O(n) lookup on slice of all urls visited should help minimize time spent inside of the critical section, which is a trivial amount of time for this example but would become relevant with scale.

WaitGroup used to prevent top level Crawl() function from returning until all child go routines are complete.

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    var str_map = make(map[string]bool)
    var mux sync.Mutex
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var crawler func(string,int)
    crawler = func(url string, depth int) {
        defer wg.Done()

        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }   

        mux.Lock()
        if _, ok := str_map[url]; ok {
            mux.Unlock()
            return;
        }else{
            str_map[url] = true
            mux.Unlock()
        }

        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q %q\n", url, body, urls)

        for _, u := range urls {
            wg.Add(1)
            go crawler(u, depth-1)          
        }       
    }
    wg.Add(1)
    crawler(url,depth)
    wg.Wait()   
}

func main() {
    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution (in its current state) does not printF the found urls. I would like to understand if and how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Similar idea to the accepted answer, but with no duplicate URLs fetched, and printing directly to console. defer() is not used either. We use channels to signal when goroutines complete. The SafeMap idea is lifted off the SafeCounter given previously in the tour.

For the child goroutines, we create an array of channels, and wait until every child returns, by waiting on the channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// SafeMap is safe to use concurrently.
type SafeMap struct {
    v   map[string] bool
    mux sync.Mutex
}

// SetVal sets the value for the given key.
func (m *SafeMap) SetVal(key string, val bool) {
    m.mux.Lock()
    // Lock so only one goroutine at a time can access the map c.v.
    m.v[key] = val
    m.mux.Unlock()
}

// Value returns the current value of the counter for the given key.
func (m *SafeMap) GetVal(key string) bool {
    m.mux.Lock()
    // Lock so only one goroutine at a time can access the map c.v.
    defer m.mux.Unlock()
    return m.v[key]
}

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, status chan bool, urlMap SafeMap) {

    // Check if we fetched this url previously.
    if ok := urlMap.GetVal(url); ok {
        //fmt.Println("Already fetched url!")
        status <- true
        return 
    }

    // Marking this url as fetched already.
    urlMap.SetVal(url, true)

    if depth <= 0 {
        status <- false
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        status <- false
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

    statuses := make ([]chan bool, len(urls)) 
    for index, u := range urls {
        statuses[index] = make (chan bool)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, statuses[index], urlMap)
    }

    // Wait for child goroutines.
    for _, childstatus := range(statuses) {
        <- childstatus
    }

    // And now this goroutine can finish.
    status <- true

    return
}

func main() {
    urlMap := SafeMap{v: make(map[string] bool)}
    status := make(chan bool)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, status, urlMap)
    <- status
}
```

Comment: Thanks, clean solution. This answer lead me to the docs on Channel Synchronization and stays within the context of the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 3):

I think using a map (the same way we could use a set in other languages) and a mutex is the easiest approach:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()
    if depth <= 0 || IsVisited(url) {
        return
    }
    visit[url] = true
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        //
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}

func IsVisited(s string) bool {
    _, ok := visit[s]
    return ok
}

var mux sync.Mutex

var visit = make(map[string]bool)

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be parallel. Here we are locking the mutex at the beginning of Crawler, so basically at a time, only 1 thread/routine of Crawler can execute (because only 1 has locked the mutex and will release it when it returns). I think the call to fetcher should be outside the lock, since in a practical situation that call might take some time and that's why we are aiming to use routines

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. I use empty structs as values in the safe cache because they are not assigned any memory. I based it off os [whossname](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2161613/whossname)'s solution.

```golang
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
    )
    
    type Fetcher interface {
        // Fetch returns the body of URL and
        // a slice of URLs found on that page.
        Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
    }
    
    type safeCache struct {
        m map[string]struct{}
        c sync.Mutex
    } 
    
    func (s *safeCache) Get(key string) bool {
        s.c.Lock()
        defer s.c.Unlock()
        if _,ok:=s.m[key];!ok{
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func (s *safeCache) Set(key string) {
        s.c.Lock()
        s.m[key] = struct{}{}
        s.c.Unlock()
        return
    }
    
    // Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
    // pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
    func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, cach safeCache) {
        defer wg.Done()
        // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
        // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
        // This implementation doesn't do either:
        cach.Set(url)
        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
        for _, u := range urls {
            if found := cach.Get(u); !found{
                wg.Add(1)
                go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, cach)
            }   
        }
        return
    }
    
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    
    func main() {
        urlSafe := safeCache{m: make(map[string]struct{})}
        wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, urlSafe)
        wg.Wait()
    }
    
    // fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
    type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult
    
    type fakeResult struct {
        body string
        urls []string
    }
    
    func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
        if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
            return res.body, res.urls, nil
        }
        return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
    }
    
    // fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
    var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
        "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
            "The Go Programming Language",
            []string{
                "https://golang.org/pkg/",
                "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            },
        },
        "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
            "Packages",
            []string{
                "https://golang.org/",
                "https://golang.org/cmd/",
                "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
                "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
            },
        },
        "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
            "Package fmt",
            []string{
                "https://golang.org/",
                "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            },
        },
        "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
            "Package os",
            []string{
                "https://golang.org/",
                "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is my solution.  Except the global map, I only had to change the contents of `Crawl`.  Like other solutions, I used `sync.Map` and `sync.WaitGroup`.  I've blocked out the important parts.

```go
var m sync.Map

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    // Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    /////////////////////////////////////
    _, ok := m.LoadOrStore(url, url)   //
    if ok {                            //
        return                         //
    }                                  //
    /////////////////////////////////////
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    // Fetch URLs in parallel.
    /////////////////////////////////////
    var wg sync.WaitGroup              //
    defer wg.Wait()                    //
    for _, u := range urls {           //
        wg.Add(1)                      //
        go func(u string) {            //
            defer wg.Done()            //
            Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher) //
        }(u)                           //
    }                                  //
    /////////////////////////////////////
    return
}
```

Comment: I (by much looking at other people's code) came up with the same solution as I think it is the cleanest and uses maximum sync primitives.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I have a "master" routine that listens to a channel of urls and starts new crawling routine (which puts crawled urls into the channel) if it finds new urls to crawl.

Instead of explicitly closing the channel, I have a counter for unfinished crawling goroutines, and when the counter is 0, the program exits because it has nothing to wait for.

```
func doCrawl(url string, fetcher Fetcher, results chan []string) {
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    results <- urls

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    }
}



func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    results := make(chan []string)
    crawled := make(map[string]bool)
    go doCrawl(url, fetcher, results)
    // counter for unfinished crawling goroutines
    toWait := 1

    for urls := range results {
        toWait--

        for _, u := range urls {
            if !crawled[u] {
                crawled[u] = true
                go doCrawl(u, fetcher, results)
                toWait++
            }
        }

        if toWait == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it with a simple channel, where all the goroutines send their messages. To ensure that it is closed when there is no more goroutines I use a safe counter, that close the channel when the counter is 0.

```
type Msg struct {
    url string
    body string
}

type SafeCounter struct {
    v int
    mux sync.Mutex
}

func (c *SafeCounter) inc() {
    c.mux.Lock()
    defer c.mux.Unlock()
    c.v++   
}

func (c *SafeCounter) dec(ch chan Msg) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    defer c.mux.Unlock()
    c.v--
    if c.v == 0 {
        close(ch)
    }
}

var goes SafeCounter = SafeCounter{v: 0}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, ch chan Msg) {
    defer goes.dec(ch)
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    if !cache.existsAndRegister(url) {
        body, urls, err :=  fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        ch <- Msg{url, body}
        for _, u := range urls {
            goes.inc()
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, ch)
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan Msg, 100)
    goes.inc()
    go Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, ch)
    for m := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", m.url, m.body)
    }
}
```

Note that the safe counter must be incremented outside of the goroutine.

Answer (score 1):

I passed the safeCounter and waitGroup to the Crawl function and then use safeCounter to jump over urls that have been visited, waitGroup to prevent early exit out of the current goroutine.

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, c *SafeCounter, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    c.mux.Lock()
    c.v[url]++
    c.mux.Unlock()

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        c.mux.Lock()
        i := c.v[u]
        c.mux.Unlock()
        if i == 1 {
            continue
        }
        wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, c, wg)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    c := SafeCounter{v: make(map[string]int)}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, &c, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version (inspired by [@fasmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680661/fasmat)s answer) – this one prevents fetching the same URL twice by utilizing custom cache with [RWMutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex).

```golang
type Cache struct {
    data map[string]fakeResult
    mux sync.RWMutex
}

var cache = Cache{data: make(map[string]fakeResult)}

//cache adds new page to the global cache
func (c *Cache) cache(url string) fakeResult {
    c.mux.Lock()

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        body = err.Error()
    }

    data := fakeResult{body, urls}
    c.data[url] = data

    c.mux.Unlock()

    return data
}

//Visit visites the page at given url and caches it if needec
func (c *Cache) Visit(url string) (data fakeResult, alreadyCached bool) {
    c.mux.RLock()
    data, alreadyCached = c.data[url]
    c.mux.RUnlock()

    if !alreadyCached {
        data = c.cache(url)
    }

    return data, alreadyCached
}

/*
Crawl crawles all pages reachable from url and within the depth (given by args).
Fetches pages using given fetcher and caches them in the global cache.
Continously sends newly discovered pages to the out channel.
*/
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, out chan string) {
    defer close(out)

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    data, alreadyCached := cache.Visit(url)
    if alreadyCached {
        return
    }

    //send newly discovered page to out channel
    out <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q", url, data.body)

    //visit linked pages
    res := make([]chan string, len(data.urls))

    for i, link := range data.urls {
        res[i] = make(chan string)
        go Crawl(link, depth-1, fetcher, res[i])
    }

    //send newly discovered pages from links to out channel
    for i := range res {
        for s := range res[i] {
            out <- s
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    res := make(chan string)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, res)

    for page := range res {
        fmt.Println(page)   
    }
}
```

Aside from not fetching URLs twice, this solution doesn't use the fact of knowing the total number of pages in advance (works for any number of pages) and doesn't falsely limit/extend program execution time by timers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to go, so grain of salt, but this solution seems to me like it'd be more idiomatic. It uses a single channel for all of the results, a single channel for all of the crawl requests (an attempt to crawl a specific url), and a wait group for keeping track of completion. The main Crawl call acts as the distributor of the crawl requests to worker processes (while handling deduplication) and acts as the tracker for how many crawl requests are pending.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type FetchResult struct {
    url  string
    body string
    err  error
}

type CrawlRequest struct {
    url   string
    depth int
}

type Crawler struct {
    depth           int
    fetcher         Fetcher
    results         chan FetchResult
    crawlRequests   chan CrawlRequest
    urlReservations map[string]bool
    waitGroup       *sync.WaitGroup
}

func (crawler Crawler) Crawl(url string, depth int) {
    defer crawler.waitGroup.Done()

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := crawler.fetcher.Fetch(url)
    crawler.results <- FetchResult{url, body, err}

    if len(urls) == 0 {
        return
    }

    crawler.waitGroup.Add(len(urls))
    for _, url := range urls {
        crawler.crawlRequests <- CrawlRequest{url, depth - 1}
    }
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) (results chan FetchResult) {
    results = make(chan FetchResult)
    urlReservations := make(map[string]bool)
    crawler := Crawler{
        crawlRequests: make(chan CrawlRequest),
        depth:         depth,
        fetcher:       fetcher,
        results:       results,
        waitGroup:     &sync.WaitGroup{},
    }

    crawler.waitGroup.Add(1)

    // Listen for crawlRequests, pass them through to the caller if they aren't duplicates.
    go func() {
        for crawlRequest := range crawler.crawlRequests {
            if _, isReserved := urlReservations[crawlRequest.url]; isReserved {
                crawler.waitGroup.Done()
                continue
            }
            urlReservations[crawlRequest.url] = true
            go crawler.Crawl(crawlRequest.url, crawlRequest.depth)
        }
    }()

    // Wait for the wait group to finish, and then close the channel
    go func() {
        crawler.waitGroup.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    // Send the first crawl request to the channel
    crawler.crawlRequests <- CrawlRequest{url, depth}

    return
}

func main() {
    results := Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    for result := range results {
        if result.err != nil {
            fmt.Println(result.err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", result.url, result.body)
    }

    fmt.Printf("done!")
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I had a problem that the main function doesn't wait on the goroutines to print their statuses and finish. I checked that the previous slide used a solution with waiting of 1 second before exiting, and I decided to use that approach. In practice though, I believe some coordinating mechanism is better.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type SafeMap struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    v  map[string]bool
}

// Sets the given key to true.
func (sm *SafeMap) Set(key string) {
    sm.mu.Lock()
    sm.v[key] = true
    sm.mu.Unlock()
}

// Get returns the current value for the given key.
func (sm *SafeMap) Get(key string) bool {
    sm.mu.Lock()
    defer sm.mu.Unlock()
    return sm.v[key]
}

var safeMap = SafeMap{v: make(map[string]bool)}

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    
    // if the value exists, don't fetch it twice
    if safeMap.Get(url) {
        return  
    }
    
    // check if there is an error fetching
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    safeMap.Set(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    
    // list contents and crawl recursively
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
}

func main() {
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to change any signatures or introduce any new stuff in the global scope. We can use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to wait for the `recurse` goroutines to finish. A `map` from a strings to empty structs acts as a set, and is the most efficient way to keep count of the already crawled URLs.

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    visited := make(map[string]struct{})
    var mu sync.Mutex
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var recurse func(string, int)
    recurse = func(url string, depth int) {
        defer wg.Done()

        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }

        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()

        if _, ok := visited[url]; ok {
            return
        }
        visited[url] = struct{}{}

        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

        for _, u := range urls {
            wg.Add(1)
            go recurse(u, depth-1)
        }
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go recurse(url, depth)
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}
```

**Full demo on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xLy_wA5wwMG)**

Answer (score 0):

I use slice to avoid crawl the url twice，the recursive version without the concurrency is ok， but not sure about this concurrency version.

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    var str_arrs []string
    var mux sync.Mutex

    var crawl func(string, int)
    crawl = func(url string, depth int) {
        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }

        mux.Lock()
        for _, v := range str_arrs {
            if url == v {
                mux.Unlock()
                return
            }
        }
        str_arrs = append(str_arrs, url)
        mux.Unlock()

        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
        for _, u := range urls {
            go crawl(u, depth-1) // could delete “go” then it is recursive
        }
    }

    crawl(url, depth)
    return
}

func main() {
    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, using sync.WaitGroup and a SafeCache of fetched urls:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Safe to use concurrently
type SafeCache struct {
    fetched map[string]string
    mux     sync.Mutex
}

func (c *SafeCache) Add(url, body string) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    defer c.mux.Unlock()

    if _, ok := c.fetched[url]; !ok {
        c.fetched[url] = body
    }
}

func (c *SafeCache) Contains(url string) bool {
    c.mux.Lock()
    defer c.mux.Unlock()

    _, ok := c.fetched[url]
    return ok
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, cache SafeCache,
    wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    cache.Add(url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        if !cache.Contains(u) {
            wg.Add(1)
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, cache, wg)
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    cache := SafeCache{fetched: make(map[string]string)}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, cache, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: You could "merge" `SafeCache.Add()` and `SafeCache.Contains()` in a single method. Then you could use this new method to return from `Crawl()` before invoking `fetcher.Fetch(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple solution for parallelization using only sync waitGroup.

```html
var fetchedUrlMap = make(map[string]bool)
var mutex sync.Mutex

func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
 //fmt.Println("In Crawl2 with url" , url)
 if _, ok := fetchedUrlMap[url]; ok {
  return
 }

 if depth <= 0 {
  return
 }
 body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
 mutex.Lock()
 fetchedUrlMap[url] = true
 mutex.Unlock()
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
 }
 fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

 var wg sync.WaitGroup
 for _, u := range urls {
  // fmt.Println("Solving for ", u)
  wg.Add(1)
  go func(uv string) {
   Crawl(uv, depth-1, fetcher)
   wg.Done()
  }(u)
 }
 wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, set map[string]bool) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    // use a set to identify if the URL should be traversed or not
    if set[url] == true {
        wg.Done()
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
        set[url] = true
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
        for _, u := range urls {
            Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, set)
        }

    }

}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    wg.Add(6)
    collectedURLs := make(map[string]bool)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, collectedURLs)
    wg.Wait()
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the Solutions here don't work out for me (including accepted answer), I'll upload my own inspired by Kamil (special thanks :) (no dups/all valid URLs)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, set map[string]bool) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    if depth <= 0 { return }
    // use a set to identify if the URL should be traversed or not
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
    set[url] = true
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        if set[u] == false {
            wg.Add(1)
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, set)
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    collectedURLs := make(map[string]bool)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, collectedURLs)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Exercise: Web Crawler
In this exercise you'll use Go's concurrency features to parallelize a web crawler.

Modify the Crawl function to fetch URLs in parallel without fetching the same URL twice.

Hint: you can keep a cache of the URLs that have been fetched on a map, but maps alone are not safe for concurrent use!
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type Response struct {
    url  string
    urls []string
    body string
    err  error
}

var ch chan Response = make(chan Response)
var fetched map[string]bool = make(map[string]bool)
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mu sync.Mutex

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    var fetch func(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher)
    wg.Add(1)
    recv := func() {
        for res := range ch {
            body, _, err := res.body, res.urls, res.err
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
        }
    }

    fetch = func(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
        time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
        defer wg.Done()
        if depth <= 0 || fetched[url] {
            return
        }
        mu.Lock()
        fetched[url] = true
        mu.Unlock()
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        for _, u := range urls {
            wg.Add(1)
            go fetch(u, depth-1, fetcher)
        }
        ch <- Response{url, urls, body, err}
    }

    go fetch(url, depth, fetcher)
    go recv()
    return
}

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    wg.Wait()
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd1/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd2/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

https://gist.github.com/gaogao1030/5d63ed925534f3610ccb7e25ed46992a

Answer (score 0):

Super-simple solution, using one channel per fetched URL to wait for GoRoutines crawling the URLs in the corresponding body.
Duplicate URLs are avoided using a `UrlCache` struct with a mutex and a `map[string]struct{}` (this saves memory wrt a map of booleans).

Side effects, potentially causing deadlocks, are mitigated by using defer for both mutex locking and channels writes.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type UrlCache struct {
    v   map[string]struct{}
    mux sync.Mutex
}

func NewUrlCache() *UrlCache {
    res := UrlCache{}
    res.v = make(map[string]struct{})

    return &res
}

func (c *UrlCache) check(url string) bool {
    c.mux.Lock()
    defer c.mux.Unlock()

    if _, p := c.v[url]; !p {
        c.v[url] = struct{}{}
        return false
    }
    return true
}

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, uc *UrlCache, c chan struct{}) {
    defer func() { c <- struct{}{} }()

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    if uc.check(url) {
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    ci := make(chan struct{})
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, uc, ci)
    }
    // Wait for parallel crowl to finish
    for range urls {
        <-ci
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, NewUrlCache(), c)

    <-c
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution. Defer is a really powerful semantic in golang.

```
var urlcache FetchedUrls

func (urlcache *FetchedUrls) CacheIfNotPresent(url string) bool {
    urlcache.m.Lock()
    defer urlcache.m.Unlock()
    _, ok := urlcache.urls[url]
    if !ok {
        urlcache.urls[url] = true
    }
    return !ok
}

func BlockOnChan(ch chan int) {
    <-ch
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, ch chan int) {
    defer close(ch)
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    
    if !urlcache.CacheIfNotPresent(url) {
        return
    }
    
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        fch := make(chan int)
        defer BlockOnChan(fch)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, fch)
    }
    
}

func main() {
    urlcache.urls = make(map[string]bool)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, make(chan int))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my solution for others to reference. Hope it helps
Being able to compare our different approaches is just great!

You can try below code in [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Ho7rGFIjRMj)

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    defer wg.Done()
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    } else if _, ok := fetched.Load(url); ok {
        fmt.Printf("Skipping (already fetched): %s\n", url)
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    fetched.Store(url, nil)
    for _, u := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
}

// As there could be many types of events leading to errors when
//  fetching a url, only marking it when it is correctly processed
var fetched sync.Map
// For each Crawl, wg is incremented, and it waits for all to finish
//  on main method
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

var crawlerWG = sync.WaitGroup{}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    defer crawlerWG.Done()
    fmt.Printf("fetching data for %s\n", url)
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        crawlerWG.Add(1)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    startedAt := time.Now()
    crawlerWG.Add(1)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    crawlerWG.Wait()

    lasted := time.Since(startedAt)
    fmt.Printf("All pages crawled. It took %.2f seconds\n", lasted.Seconds())
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

var fetcherMutex = sync.RWMutex{}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {

    fetcherMutex.RLock()

    defer fetcherMutex.RUnlock()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {

        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without many locks and races:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type Cache struct {
    mutex sync.Mutex
    used  map[string]bool
}

func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    var cache Cache
    cache.used = make(map[string]bool)
    var crawler func(string, int, chan<- string)

    out := make(chan string)

    crawler = func(url string, depth int, out chan<- string) {
        defer close(out)

        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            out <- fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", err.Error())
            return
        }
        cache.mutex.Lock()
        if _, ok := cache.used[url]; ok {
            cache.mutex.Unlock()
            return
        }
        out <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
        cache.used[url] = true
        cache.mutex.Unlock()

        rets := make([]chan string, len(urls))
        for i, u := range urls {
            rets[i] = make(chan string, 2)
            go crawler(u, depth-1, rets[i])
        }

        for i := range rets {
            for line := range rets[i] {
                out <- line
            }
        }

        return
    }
    go crawler(url, depth, out)

    for line := range out {
        fmt.Print(line)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just started learning Go and here is my solution. I hope that it is simple, in a spirit of "A Tour of Go" and not using things that are not in "Tour" like `WaitGroup`. ([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ygzlPK3oPmP))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string, cache *safeCache) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, result chan string, cache *safeCache) {
    defer close(result)

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url, cache)
    if err != nil {
        result <- err.Error()
        return
    }

    result <- fmt.Sprintf("found: %s %q", url, body)

    _result := make([]chan string, len(urls))
    for i, u := range urls {
        _result[i] = make(chan string)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, _result[i], cache)
    }

    for i := range _result {
        for s := range _result[i] {
            result <- s
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    entry := "https://golang.org/"
    depth := 4
    result := make(chan string)
    cache := &safeCache{visited: make(map[string]bool)}

    go Crawl(entry, depth, fetcher, result, cache)

    for s := range result {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

type safeCache struct {
    mu      sync.Mutex
    visited map[string]bool
}

func (c *safeCache) Visit(url string) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    c.visited[url] = true
    c.mu.Unlock()
}

func (c *safeCache) IsVisited(url string) bool {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()
    return c.visited[url]
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string, cache *safeCache) (body string, urls []string, err error) {
    if cache.IsVisited(url) {
        return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("visited: %s", url)
    }
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        cache.Visit(url)
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to avoid using `sync.WaitGroup`, we can simulate it with these two channels:

1. channel `cnt` keeps the count of running goroutines (a decrement is sent to the channel before each goroutine exits).
2. channel `quit` signals that there is no more running goroutines.

```golang
type Crawler struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex
    urls map[string]struct{}
}

func (crawler *Crawler) IsVisited(url string) bool {
    crawler.mu.Lock()
    defer crawler.mu.Unlock()
    _, ok := crawler.urls[url]
    return ok
}

func (crawler *Crawler) AddVisited(url string) {
    crawler.mu.Lock()
    defer crawler.mu.Unlock()
    crawler.urls[url] = struct{}{}
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func (crawler *Crawler) Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, cnt chan int) {
    defer func() {
        cnt <- -1
    }()

    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    if crawler.IsVisited(url) {
        return
    }
    crawler.AddVisited(url)

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    cnt <- len(urls)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go crawler.Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, cnt)
    }
    return
}

func countDown(cnt, quit chan int) {
    var total int
    for {
        total += <-cnt
        if total <= 0 {
            quit <- 0
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    crawler := &Crawler{urls: make(map[string]struct{})}
    cnt, quit := make(chan int), make(chan int)
    go crawler.Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, cnt)
    go countDown(cnt, quit)
    cnt <- 1
    <-quit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution below :

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
```

Crawl function :

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, cache map[string]bool, mu *sync.Mutex) {
defer wg.Done()

if depth <= 0 {
    return
}

mu.Lock()
_, ok := cache[url]
mu.Unlock()

if ok {
    return
}

mu.Lock()
cache[url] = true
mu.Unlock()

body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)

for _, url := range urls {
    if _, ok := cache[url]; !ok {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Crawl(url, depth-1, fetcher, cache, mu)

    }
}
return
```

}

Main function :

```
func main() {
cache := make(map[string]bool)
var mu sync.Mutex
wg.Add(1)
go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, cache, &mu)
wg.Wait()
```

}

I wander what do you think about this solution?

Answer (score -1):

Using mutex and channels

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type SafeMap struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    seen map[string]bool
}

func (s *SafeMap) getVal(url string) bool {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    return s.seen[url]
}

func (s *SafeMap) setVal(url string) {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    s.seen[url] = true
}

var s = SafeMap{seen: make(map[string]bool)}

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, ch chan bool) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 || s.getVal(url) {
        ch <- false
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    
    s.setVal(url)
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        ch <- false
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    chs := make(map[string]chan bool, len(urls))
    for _, u := range urls {
        chs[u] = make(chan bool)
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, chs[u])
    }
    for _,v := range urls {
        <-chs[v]
    }
    ch <- true
    return
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, ch)
    <-ch
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type SafeCounter struct {
    sync.Mutex
    v map[string]int
}

func (c *SafeCounter) Inc(key string) {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    c.v[key]++
}

func (c *SafeCounter) Value(key string) int {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    return c.v[key]
}

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, c *SafeCounter) {
    if depth <= 0 || c.Value(url) > 0 {
        return
    }
    c.Inc(url)
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        if c.Value(u) == 0 {
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, c)
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    c := SafeCounter{v: make(map[string]int)}
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, &c)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt only using mutex, channels and goroutines

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type URLStore struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex
    seen map[string]bool
}

func (s *URLStore) Visit(url string) bool {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()
    if s.seen[url] {
        return true
    }
    s.seen[url] = true
    return false
}

var visited = URLStore{seen: make(map[string]bool)}

func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, ch chan bool) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        ch <- true
        return
    }

    if visited.Visit(url) {
        ch <- true
        return
    }

    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        ch <- true
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    childCh := make(chan bool)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, childCh)
        <-childCh
    }
    ch <- true
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, ch)
    <-ch
}
```

Comment: My implementation does attempt to parallelize the web crawling by using goroutines, but it has a significant limitation that hampers true parallel execution. Specifically, the parent goroutine waits for each child goroutine to complete before moving on to the next URL in its list. 

This waiting happens here:
For full parallel execution, I would typically not wait for each child to complete before moving on to the next one. I can use a separate mechanism to track when all goroutines are done, such as a WaitGroup or another channel-based solution.